# Pop up in HTML and CSS - The contents on this pop dissappears

Tags: html, css

I have created this popup using HTML and CSS. I am using this pop up to create a privacy policy page but the problem is that with this pop up the more information I had to the pop up, the contents at the top disappears, I am not sure why it is doing this, I have deleted some contents of this page so that I can post the code. I help you can help?

thank you

html

```css
/* Pop up */

.popup {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 3000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

@supports ( (-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(10px))) {
  .popup {
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}

.popup .header__logo-box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

.popup__content .heading-secondary {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.popup__content .heading-tertiary {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.popup__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(117, 94, 94, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.25);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.25);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.5s 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup:target {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup:target .popup__content {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  padding: 3rem;
}

.popup__close:link,
.popup__close:visited {
  color: #777;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  line-height: 1;
}

.popup__close:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.popup__close--pp:link,
.popup__close--pp:visited {
  color: #777;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13rem;
  right: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  line-height: 1;
}

.popup__close--pp:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.popup__text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup--privacy">
  <div class="popup__content">
    <div class="popup__left">
      <img src="img/Erpsoft__logo.gif" alt="ERP Soft Logo" class="header__logo-box" />
    </div>
    <div class="popup__right">
      <a href="#footer" class="popup__close--pp">&times;</a>
      <h2 class="heading-secondary">Privacy Policy</h2>
      <p class="popup__text">
        <b>Last updated: October 20, 2021</b><br /><br /> This Privacy Policy describes Our policies and procedures on the collection, use and disclosure of Your information when You use the Service and tells You about Your privacy rights and how the
        law protects You. We use Your Personal data to provide and improve the Service. By using the Service, You agree to the collection and use of information in accordance with this Privacy Policy. This Privacy Policy has been created with the help
        of the Privacy Policy Generator.
      </p>
      <h2 class="heading-secondary">Interpretation and Definitions</h2>
      <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Interpretation</h3>
      <p class="popup__text">
        The words of which the initial letter is capitalized have meanings defined under the following conditions. The following definitions shall have the same meaning regardless of whether they appear in singular or in plural.
      </p>
      <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Definitions</h3>
      <p class="popup__text">For the purposes of this Privacy Policy:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Account</b> means a unique account created for You to access our Service or parts of our Service.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Company</b> (referred to as either "the Company", "We", "Us" or "Our" in this Agreement) refers to Erpsoft.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Cookies</b> are small files that are placed on Your computer, mobile device or any other device by a website, containing the details of Your browsing history on that website among its many uses.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Country</b> refers to: United Kingdom
          </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Device</b> means any device that can access the Service such as a computer, a cellphone or a digital tablet.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Personal Data</b> is any information that relates to an identified or identifiable individual.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text"><b>Service</b> refers to the Website.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Service Provider</b> means any natural or legal person who processes the data on behalf of the Company. It refers to third-party companies or individuals employed by the Company to facilitate the Service, to provide the Service on behalf
            of the Company, to perform services related to the Service or to assist the Company in analyzing how the Service is used.
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h2 class="heading-secondary">
        Collecting and Using Your Personal Data
      </h2>
      <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Types of Data Collected</h3>
      <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Personal Data</h3>
      <p class="popup__text">
        While using Our Service, We may ask You to provide Us with certain personally identifiable information that can be used to contact or identify You. Personally identifiable information may include, but is not limited to:
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">Email address</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">First name and last name</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">Phone number</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            Address, State, Province, ZIP/Postal code, City
          </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">Usage Data</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Usage Data</h3>
      <p class="popup__text">
        Usage Data is collected automatically when using the Service.<br /><br /> Usage Data may include information such as Your Device's Internet Protocol address (e.g. IP address), browser type, browser version, the pages of our Service that You visit,
        the time and date of Your visit, the time spent on those pages, unique device identifiers and other diagnostic data.<br /><br /> When You access the Service by or through a mobile device, We may collect certain information automatically, including,
        but not limited to, the type of mobile device You use, Your mobile device unique ID, the IP address of Your mobile device, Your mobile operating system, the type of mobile Internet browser You use, unique device identifiers and other diagnostic
        data.
        <br /><br /> We may also collect information that Your browser sends whenever You visit our Service or when You access the Service by or through a mobile device.
      </p>
      <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Tracking Technologies and Cookies</h3>
      <p class="popup__text">
        We use Cookies and similar tracking technologies to track the activity on Our Service and store certain information. Tracking technologies used are beacons, tags, and scripts to collect and track information and to improve and analyze Our Service. The
        technologies We use may include:
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Cookies or Browser Cookies.</b> A cookie is a small file placed on Your Device. You can instruct Your browser to refuse all Cookies or to indicate when a Cookie is being sent. However, if You do not accept Cookies, You may not be able to
            use some parts of our Service. Unless you have adjusted Your browser setting so that it will refuse Cookies, our Service may use Cookies.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="popup__text">
            <b>Flash Cookies.</b> Certain features of our Service may use local stored objects (or Flash Cookies) to collect and store information about Your preferences or Your activity on our Service. Flash Cookies are not managed by the same browser
            settings as those used for Browser Cookies. For more information on how You can delete Flash Cookies, please read "Where can I change the settings for disabling, or deleting local shared objects?" available at
            <a href="https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/disable-local-shared-objects-flash.html#main_Where_can_I_change_the_settings_for_disabling__or_deleting_local_shared_objects_">https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/disable-local-shared-objects-flash.html#main_Where_can_I_change_the_settings_for_disabling__or_deleting_local_shared_objects_</a
                    >
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>Web Beacons.</b> Certain sections of our Service and our
                    emails may contain small electronic files known as web beacons
                    (also referred to as clear gifs, pixel tags, and single-pixel
                    gifs) that permit the Company, for example, to count users who
                    have visited those pages or opened an email and for other
                    related website statistics (for example, recording the
                    popularity of a certain section and verifying system and server
                    integrity).
                  </p>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <p class="popup__text">
                Cookies can be "Persistent" or "Session" Cookies. Persistent Cookies
                remain on Your personal computer or mobile device when You go
                offline, while Session Cookies are deleted as soon as You close Your
                web browser. You can learn more about cookies here: Cookies by
                TermsFeed Generator.
              </p>
              <p class="popup__text">
                We use both Session and Persistent Cookies for the purposes set out
                below:
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>Necessary / Essential Cookies</b>
                  </p>
                  <p class="popup__text">Type: Session Cookies</p>
                  <p class="popup__text">Administered by: Us</p>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    Purpose: These Cookies are essential to provide You with
                    services available through the Website and to enable You to use
                    some of its features. They help to authenticate users and
                    prevent fraudulent use of user accounts. Without these Cookies,
                    the services that You have asked for cannot be provided, and We
                    only use these Cookies to provide You with those services.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>Cookies Policy / Notice Acceptance Cookies</b>
                  </p>
                  <p class="popup__text">Type: Persistent Cookies</p>
                  <p class="popup__text">Administered by: Us</p>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    Purpose: These Cookies identify if users have accepted the use
                    of cookies on the Website.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>Functionality Cookies</b>
                  </p>
                  <p class="popup__text">Type: Persistent Cookies</p>
                  <p class="popup__text">Administered by: Us</p>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    Purpose: These Cookies allow us to remember choices You make
                    when You use the Website, such as remembering your login details
                    or language preference. The purpose of these Cookies is to
                    provide You with a more personal experience and to avoid You
                    having to re-enter your preferences every time You use the
                    Website.
                  </p>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <p class="popup__text">
                For more information about the cookies we use and your choices
                regarding cookies, please visit our Cookies Policy or the Cookies
                section of our Privacy Policy.
              </p>
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">Use of Your Personal Data</h2>
              <p class="popup__text">
                The Company may use Personal Data for the following purposes:
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>To provide and maintain our Service,</b> including to monitor
                    the usage of our Service.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>To manage Your Account:</b> to manage Your registration as a
                    user of the Service. The Personal Data You provide can give You
                    access to different functionalities of the Service that are
                    available to You as a registered user.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>For the performance of a contract:</b> the development,
                    compliance and undertaking of the purchase contract for the
                    products, items or services You have purchased or of any other
                    contract with Us through the Service.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>To contact You:</b> To contact You by email, telephone calls,
                    SMS, or other equivalent forms of electronic communication, such
                    as a mobile application's push notifications regarding updates
                    or informative communications related to the functionalities,
                    products or contracted services, including the security updates,
                    when necessary or reasonable for their implementation.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>To provide You</b> with news, special offers and general
                    information about other goods, services and events which we
                    offer that are similar to those that you have already purchased
                    or enquired about unless You have opted not to receive such
                    information.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>To manage Your requests:</b> To attend and manage Your
                    requests to Us.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>For business transfers:</b> We may use Your information to
                    evaluate or conduct a merger, divestiture, restructuring,
                    reorganization, dissolution, or other sale or transfer of some
                    or all of Our assets, whether as a going concern or as part of
                    bankruptcy, liquidation, or similar proceeding, in which
                    Personal Data held by Us about our Service users is among the
                    assets transferred.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>For other purposes:</b> We may use Your information for other
                    purposes, such as data analysis, identifying usage trends,
                    determining the effectiveness of our promotional campaigns and
                    to evaluate and improve our Service, products, services,
                    marketing and your experience.
                  </p>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <p class="popup__text">
                We may share Your personal information in the following situations:
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>With Service Providers:</b> We may share Your personal
                    information with Service Providers to monitor and analyze the
                    use of our Service, to contact You.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>For business transfers:</b> We may share or transfer Your
                    personal information in connection with, or during negotiations
                    of, any merger, sale of Company assets, financing, or
                    acquisition of all or a portion of Our business to another
                    company.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>With Affiliates:</b> We may share Your information with Our
                    affiliates, in which case we will require those affiliates to
                    honor this Privacy Policy. Affiliates include Our parent company
                    and any other subsidiaries, joint venture partners or other
                    companies that We control or that are under common control with
                    Us.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>With business partners:</b> when You share personal
                    information or otherwise interact in the public areas with other
                    users, such information may be viewed by all users and may be
                    publicly distributed outside.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>With other users:</b> We may share Your information with Our
                    business partners to offer You certain products, services or
                    promotions.
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    <b>With Your consent:</b> We may disclose Your personal
                    information for any other purpose with Your consent.
                  </p>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">Retention of Your Personal Data</h2>
              <p class="popup__text">
                The Company will retain Your Personal Data only for as long as is
                necessary for the purposes set out in this Privacy Policy. We will
                retain and use Your Personal Data to the extent necessary to comply
                with our legal obligations (for example, if we are required to
                retain your data to comply with applicable laws), resolve disputes,
                and enforce our legal agreements and policies.<br /><br />
              </p>
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">Transfer of Your Personal Data</h2>
              <p class="popup__text">
                Your information, including Personal Data, is processed at the
                Company's operating offices and in any other places where the
                parties involved in the processing are located. It means that this
                information may be transferred to — and maintained on — computers
                located outside of Your state, province, country or other
                governmental jurisdiction where the data protection laws may differ
                than those from Your jurisdiction. <br /><br />
    
                Your consent to this Privacy Policy followed by Your submission of
                such information represents Your agreement to that transfer.<br /><br />
              </p>
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">Disclosure of Your Personal Data</h2>
              <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Law enforcement</h3>
              <p class="popup__text">
                Under certain circumstances, the Company may be required to disclose
                Your Personal Data if required to do so by law or in response to
                valid requests by public authorities (e.g. a court or a government
                agency).
              </p>
              <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Other legal requirements</h3>
              <p class="popup__text">
                The Company may disclose Your Personal Data in the good faith belief
                that such action is necessary to:
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">Comply with a legal obligation</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    Protect and defend the rights or property of the Company
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    Prevent or investigate possible wrongdoing in connection with
                    the Service
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    Protect the personal safety of Users of the Service or the
                    public
                  </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">Protect against legal liability</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Security of Your Personal Data</h3>
              <p class="popup__text">
                The security of Your Personal Data is important to Us, but remember
                that no method of transmission over the Internet, or method of
                electronic storage is 100% secure. While We strive to use
                commercially acceptable means to protect Your Personal Data, We
                cannot guarantee its absolute security.
              </p>
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">Children's Privacy</h2>
              <p class="popup__text">
                Our Service does not address anyone under the age of 13. We do not
                knowingly collect personally identifiable information from anyone
                under the age of 13. If You are a parent or guardian and You are
                aware that Your child has provided Us with Personal Data, please
                contact Us. If We become aware that We have collected Personal Data
                from anyone under the age of 13 without verification of parental
                consent, We take steps to remove that information from Our servers.
                <br /><br />
    
                If We need to rely on consent as a legal basis for processing Your
                information and Your country requires consent from a parent, We may
                require Your parent's consent before We collect and use that
                information.
              </p>
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">Links to Other Websites</h2>
              <p class="popup__text">
                Our Service may contain links to other websites that are not
                operated by Us. If You click on a third party link, You will be
                directed to that third party's site. We strongly advise You to
                review the Privacy Policy of every site You visit. <br /><br />
    
                We have no control over and assume no responsibility for the
                content, privacy policies or practices of any third party sites or
                services.
              </p>
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">Changes to this Privacy Policy</h2>
              <p class="popup__text">
                We may update Our Privacy Policy from time to time. We will notify
                You of any changes by posting the new Privacy Policy on this page.
                <br /><br />
    
                We will let You know via email and/or a prominent notice on Our
                Service, prior to the change becoming effective and update the "Last
                updated" date at the top of this Privacy Policy. <br /><br />
    
                You are advised to review this Privacy Policy periodically for any
                changes. Changes to this Privacy Policy are effective when they are
                posted on this page.
              </p>
              <h2 class="heading-secondary">Contact Us</h2>
              <p class="popup__text">
                If you have any questions about this Privacy Policy, You can contact
                us:
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">By email: info@erpsoft.co.uk</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p class="popup__text">
                    By visiting this page on our website:
                    <a href="www.erpsoft.co.uk">www.erpsoft.co.uk</a>
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS class names `popup` having issues with `opacity: 0;visibility: hidden;`
and class `popup__content` having issue with `opacity: 0;`
Becuase of `opacity:0;` and `visibility: hidden;` the page contents are not showing.

**opacity:**

The CSS `opacity` property is the first way that might come to your mind to change transparency. But this property can't come to the rescue all the time, especially when there is a background image with text in it that you want to make transparent.

The `opacity` property takes values from `0.0` to `1.0`, with `1` being the default value for all elements. The lower the value, the more transparent. So if an element is given an opacity of `0`, it would be `invisible`.

**visibility:**

The `visibility` property specifies whether or not an element is `visible`.

***Updated CSS:***

```
.popup {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 3000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden; */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
@supports ( (-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(10px))) {
  .popup {
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}
.popup .header__logo-box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10rem;
}
.popup__content .heading-secondary {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.popup__content .heading-tertiary {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.popup__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(117, 94, 94, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.25);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.25);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.5s 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
}
.popup:target {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.popup:target .popup__content {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  padding: 3rem;
}
.popup__close:link,
.popup__close:visited {
  color: #777;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  line-height: 1;
}
.popup__close:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
}
.popup__close--pp:link,
.popup__close--pp:visited {
  color: #777;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13rem;
  right: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  line-height: 1;
}
.popup__close--pp:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
}
.popup__text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

[image]

[DEMO Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/mzn1hpqs/)

Comment: Hi Jeba, Thank you sir for your help. I tried the code but it doesn't work. It maybe better instead of complicating matters I just create a page for the privacy page?

Comment: @HimatVarsani Have you checked the demo link? Are you able to see the popup contents? What is the issue you are facing now? Thank you.

Comment: The contents isn't visible and so small. I think it might be better to create a separate page for the privacy. I wanted the pop-up to be as shown initially that I created but with a scroll to see all the contents. Thank you again @jebasuthan for your kind help

Comment: Hi @jebasuthan, I'd checked the demo link but the issue facing is that the contents and the popup seems to be so small, it's not visible. I wanted to have the original size contents but enable to scroll and see all the contents.